# Nested while loop in bash

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script

In a txt file, I have a list of sites that I'd like to visit. Each of them provides a list of pages on the particular site to be visited (when called without page parameter) via list.php.
The problem is that the inside loop is getting executed right after the first pass through the outside loop and that causes running multiple instances of chromium browser. 
What I'd like to achieve is visiting each page and closing the browser after that, then visiting another etc.

```
while read sites; do 
    wget -qO- "$sites/list.php" | 
        while read page; do 
           chromium "$sites/$page" & sleep 1
           pkill --oldest chromium
           wget -qO- "$sites/list.php?page=$page"
         done
done < sites.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't send `chromium` to the background:

```
chromium "$sites/$page" & sleep 1
```

Keep it in the foreground:

```
chromium "$sites/$page"
sleep 1
```

Comment: And if assuming I need it to be running on the background? I guess making a single loop by combining the URLs before the inner loop, right?

Comment: @Alexis if you run it in the background, you need to use `wait`. But what's the point?

Answer (score 1):

After opening a new session, the code worked as expected, it was just some fluke

UPDATE: to make it reliable, the only thing needed is to increase the sleep interval by a few seconds